# How should this relation be designed in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, relational-database

Relative beginner to backend development here - I've been working with rails for a month or so. I've got a grip of most things but I'm struggling with planning database tables with relations.

I'm in the process of adding keys to an existing database. The current structure is as follows:

A user has_many agreements. Agreements belong_to a user.

What I need now is for an agreement to have a GarageKey assigned. This key needs to be shareable to other users.

I started out thinking about it like this:

Agreements has_one GarageKey which the User then reaches from User->Agreement->GarageKey. There then needs to be a join table (SharedKeys) which specify the shared_keys.

However, this feels weird. This means that the user has one key in User->Agreement->Garagekey and the rest of his keys over at User->SharedKeys.

In an ideal scenario I'd like to have all keys at User->Keys, but I'm struggling with how to make this relation. It's very important to have the initial key bound by agreement, but I'm kind of stumped as to what to do with the rest.

Any Ideas?

Comment: WHat exactly does `This key needs to be shareable to other users` means?

Comment: @AndreyDeineko - It means that the owner of the agreement can invite other Users to use the key.